# What's the best way to JOIN this?

Tags: mysql

Excuse for the beginner question, but I'm stucked with this, not knowing where I did wrong. I have two tables presenting as follows, and need to join them,

I need to join it so that the data shows the *code, year, median_age_est* and *all_population* based on the year. *For example, UK, 1959, 39.9, 50055568*

Here is the code that I tried to join the two:

```
SELECT 
a.Code as a_country_code,
a.Median_age_est,
a.year as a_year,
b.All_pop_uk
FROM dbo.['median-age$'] a  
RIGHT JOIN dbo.['historic-and-un-pop-projections$'] b
ON a.code = b.code
WHERE a.code = 'GBR'
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just include year in your join condition!

```sql
SELECT 
a.Code as a_country_code,
a.Median_age_est,
a.year as a_year,
b.All_pop_uk
FROM dbo.['median-age$'] a  
RIGHT JOIN dbo.['historic-and-un-pop-projections$'] b
ON a.code = b.code and a.year = b.year
WHERE a.code = 'GBR'
```

Comment: oh my god, yes! thanks a lot, I know it's a super basic question but I've been struggled to find the answer :-)

Comment: @Khai please accept the answer and vote up if it was hlepful, thanks.